# [Shopware6]: How to reuse the customer selection component in administration?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to create a custom-field that is an entity-single-select for customers, exactly like the one in the sw-order module as seen here
[sw-order-create-details-header > sw-entity-single-select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZEEW.png)

Is there some way for me, to configure the look of my custom-field to be the same as the extended select-field in the sw-order module?
With that i mean, inclusive of firstName, lastName, address and customernumber?
(Without creating a a new component)

What i have so far is this:

```
    protected $customFields =  [
    [
        'name' => 'referrer_set',
        'config' => [
            'label' => [
                'en-GB' => 'Referrer',
                'de-DE' => 'Referrer',
            ],
        ],
        'customFields' => [
            [
                'active' => true,
                'name' => 'refferer_set',
                'type' => CustomFieldTypes::ENTITY,
                'config' => [
                    'componentName' => 'sw-entity-single-select',
                    'entity' => CustomerDefinition::ENTITY_NAME,
                    'placeholder' => "Wurde empfohlen von ...",
                    'highlightSearchTerm' => true,
                    'allowEntityCreation' => false,
                    'show-clearable-button' => true,
                    'labelProperty' => 'firstName',
                    'label' => [
                        'en-GB' => 'Empfohlen von',
                        'de-DE' => 'Empfohlen von',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'relations' => [
            [
                'entityName' => CustomerDefinition::ENTITY_NAME,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't quite so trivial to achieve.

You could override the component which is responsible for rendering custom fields `sw-form-field-renderer`.

Inside the override you check if it is your specific custom field that should be rendered. In the template of the override you then set the content of the slot `result-item`, which is a corresponding to each option in the dropdown. You'll additionally have to extend the binds of the component with a criteria to add the billing address of the customer as an association.

The override:

```js
import template from './sw-form-field-renderer.html.twig';

const { Component } = Shopware;
const { Criteria } = Shopware.Data;

Component.override('sw-form-field-renderer', {
    template,

    computed: {
        isMyCustomField() {
            return this.config.componentName === 'sw-entity-single-select' && this.$attrs.name === 'refferer_set';
        },

        bind() {
            const bind = this.$super('bind');

            if (this.isMyCustomField) {
                const criteria = new Criteria;
                criteria.addAssociation('defaultBillingAddress.country');
                bind.criteria = criteria;
            }

            return bind;
        },
    },
});
```

The template `sw-form-field-renderer.html.twig`:

```html
{% block sw_form_field_renderer_scope_slots %}
{% parent %}
<template
    v-if="isMyCustomField"
    #result-item="{ item, index, labelProperty, searchTerm, highlightSearchTerm, isSelected, setValue, getKey }"
>
    <!-- copy/paste from sw-order-create-details-header -->
    <li
        is="sw-select-result"
        :selected="isSelected(item)"
        v-bind="{ item, index }"
        class="sw-order-create-details-header__customer-result"
        @item-select="setValue"
    >
        <div class="sw-order-create-details-header__customer-result-item has-many-childrens">
            <div>
                <sw-highlight-text
                    v-if="highlightSearchTerm"
                    :text="getKey(item, 'firstName') || getKey(item, `translated.firstName`)"
                    :search-term="searchTerm"
                />

                <sw-highlight-text
                    v-if="highlightSearchTerm"
                    :text="getKey(item, 'lastName') || getKey(item, `translated.lastName`)"
                    :search-term="searchTerm"
                />
            </div>

            <sw-highlight-text
                v-if="highlightSearchTerm"
                :text="getKey(item, 'customerNumber') || getKey(item, `translated.customerNumber`)"
                :search-term="searchTerm"
                class="text-truncate"
            />
        </div>

        <div
            v-if="getKey(item, 'company') || getKey(item, `translated.company`)"
            class="sw-order-create-details-header__customer-result-item"
        >
            <sw-highlight-text
                v-if="highlightSearchTerm"
                :text="getKey(item, 'company') || getKey(item, `translated.company`)"
                :search-term="searchTerm"
            />
        </div>

        <div class="sw-order-create-details-header__customer-result-item text-gray-500">
            {{ item.defaultBillingAddress.street }} <br>
            {{ item.defaultBillingAddress.zipcode }} {{ item.defaultBillingAddress.city }} <br>
            {{ item.defaultBillingAddress.country.name }}
        </div>
    </li>
</template>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Worked nicely, thank you